# Stop an Object if it reached the transform value

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a 2d gameObject that behaves likes a spike trap that springs out of the ground when the character collides on the trigger. I use AddForce to the rigidbody 2D of the gameObject to manipulates its speed when coming out of the ground and I want it to just sticking out of the ground. How can I stop it when it reaches a certain tranform Y value.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public float speed;

Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start () {

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update () {

}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
       rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, speed * Time.time), ForceMode2D.Impulse);       
    }
}
```

Comment: try 'rb.AddForce(transform.up * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);'

Comment: you can check position y in Update()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain transform value, or certain transform.position value?

I'll do it like this:

```
private float threshold = 10f;
private float startPosition = 0;
private RigidBody2D pikeRigidbody;:

private void Start()
{
  startPosition =  = this.transform.position;
  pikeRigidbody = this.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
}

private void Update(){
  if(this.transform.position.y >= (startPosition.y + threshold))
  {
    pikeRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
  }
}
```

And attach the script to the pike object.

*Edited to position.y instead of position*

Comment: actually transform.position.y., I want the spike to stop when it is high enough. thanks

Comment: @RyRen updated, mark the answer as correct if it is, please.